# Run Laravel Commands with www-data user

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5.1

I made a command in Laravel 5.1 that is supposed to delete some directories from the file system.

in the `handle()` method of the command class, i did `shell_exec("whoami")`
and it returns `raheel`. However the user `raheel` has no permission on the specified directory. I want to run this command as apache `www-data` user.

How can i implement this in Laravel ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a console command, you run with `php artisan`?

Comment: [sudo as www-data user](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176997/sudo-as-another-user-with-their-environment)

Comment: Try this [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/566457): sudo -u www-data your_command

Answer (score 12):

This is how I'm running my crons:

```
su -c "php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1" -s /bin/sh www-data
```